# Expectation of $Y=X\mathbf 1_{X>t}$ in terms of the CCDF $P(Y>x)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

I have random variable $Y=XU(X-t)$ (here $U(X)$ is the unit step function, $Y$ has non-negative support and depends on other random variable $X$) which has a CCDF $P(Y>t)$. I want to write the expected value of $Y$ in terms of CCDF of $Y$. I have seen in the literature that it can be written in following way but I do not know how to prove it. Can any body provide the proof if the following expression is right? $$E(Y)=\int_t^\infty P(Y>x)dx+tP(Y>t).$$

I can prove it for the case of $t=0$ but for general positive values of $t$ I do not know how to proceed. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: Take the usual formula for nonnegative random variables $$E(Y)=\int_0^\infty P(Y>x)dx=\int_0^t P(Y>x)dx+\int_t^\infty P(Y>x)dx$$ and note that $P(Y>x)=P(X>t)=P(Y>t)$ for every $0<x<t$ hence $$\int_0^t P(Y>x)dx=tP(Y>t).$$

Comment: @Did thanks a lot.